How to translate Language switcher?
I can't seem to translate the language switcher component.
in my csv it_IT i added this:
"Language","Lingua",module,Magento_Store
"English","EN",module,Magento_Store
"Italiano","IT",module,Magento_Store

then did the commands but i don't see translations on the FE.
i know the problem isn't the commands or cache cause i just translated the store-switcher and it worked just fine; i'm wondering maybe the module is incorrect? i tried Magento_Theme as well and it didn't work either... how do you even check what module a component belongs to?
Can anybody help? Thank you
